# jQuery: catch click inside a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have such html:

```
  <a href="http://google.com" class="extended-link">
    <span class="extended-span" data-comment-href="http://example.com">text</span>
  </a>
```

and css:

```
.extended-link {
  display: inline-block;
  background: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
}

.extended-span {
  display: inline-block;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 100px 0 0 0;
}
```

and js:

```
$('.extended-span').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  window.location.href = $(this).attr('data-comment-href');
});
```

but I can't catch `.extended-span` click, it always fire outer link redirection.

is it posible to catch click inside a link (link must be clickable, except span)

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AS9WxkI8VSiMAw4NjVi2?p=preview)

Comment: also, sure in real environment in link i have another div's, h1-h6 etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `event.preventDefault();` instead of `event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: good!
btw: hm, strange, in wp on main page this work, but in inner not (but method is fired)

Answer (score 1):

**[event.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) :** Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

**[event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) :** If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

In your case you have to use the second one `event.preventDefault()` because you want to prevent the default action and fire another customized action.

```js
$('.extended-span').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  window.location.href = $(this).attr('data-comment-href');
});
```

```css
.extended-link {
  display: inline-block;
  background: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
}

.extended-span {
  display: inline-block;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 100px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://google.com" class="extended-link">
    <span class="extended-span" data-comment-href="http://example.com">text</span>
</a>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Find the following code correction:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
```

$('.extended-span').click(function(event) {

window.location.href = $(this).attr('data-comment-href');

return false;
});

});